# Graphic and value output error on jupyter notebook connected with wolfram engine

Tags: warning-messages, free-wolfram-engine, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to run the Wolfram engine in the Jupyter. I've followed this :

https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

But I have some problems.

[image]

Why isn't the graphic output working? and 1/0 aren't returns Complex Infinite at all. also, It seems that error occurs in cmd. and why are all letters print green?

If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it. thanks.

From B.K.

Comment: Any output that are not simple text all disappeared since Mathematica version 12.2.  Currently, I use v12.3.1 on rpi 64bit, and the problems still persist. I append inline "// Print" to the commands to get the output that can be printed as multi-line texts.